# function to weigh values in each cell of the column of data frame with different rules for each one

Tags: r, math, data-manipulation, operation, weighted

I have a data frame with direct punctuations extracted from a raw data file. All deducted punctuations have different scales, so is not easy to compare them since they have different maximum and minimum values. I would like to weigh the punctuations into 0 to 5 scale, so at the moment of plotting measures, will be feasible to compare them between each other. With the method to operate row values by a single number (for example: `df$num3 <- df$num2 - df$num1`), all measures will get unexpected values because each one has different maximum value. I'm actually trying divide each result by the maximum possible (which in fact are 120, 45, 30), and then multiply the quotient by 5.

So here's the data frame with the max and min values between parenthesis:

```
              Variable Puntuación
1 Capacidades (24-120)         85
2    Planeación (9-45)         30
3     Relaciones(6-30)         20
```

The goal is to write a function that allows me to do the following operations and store/update the results in the same column:

```
(row 1- column 2) /120 * 5 , (row 2- column 2) /45 * 5, (row 3- column 2) /30 * 5
```

Thank you in advance for any guidance you can provide me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of your question but I think the main point is converting the data in the string to numerical data. For that reason, I'd use the following.

```
library(tidyverse)
glimpse(data)
```

... which gives:

```
Observations: 3
Variables: 2
$ Variable   <chr> "Capacidades (24-120)", "Planeación (9-45)", "Relaciones…
$ Puntuación <dbl> 85, 30, 20
```

And then:

```
data_new <- data %>% 
  separate(
    col = Variable, 
    into = c("ID", "Value"), 
    convert = F, 
    sep = "\\(") %>% 
  separate(
    col = Value, 
    into = c("Value1", "Value2"), 
    convert = F, 
    sep = "\\-") %>% 
  mutate(
    Value1 = as.integer(Value1),
    Value2 = as.integer(
      str_sub(
        Value2, start = 1L, end = -2L
        )
      )
    )

glimpse(data_new)
```

... which gives:

```
Observations: 3
Variables: 4
$ ID         <chr> "Capacidades ", "Planeación ", "Relaciones"
$ Value1     <int> 24, 9, 6
$ Value2     <int> 120, 45, 30
$ Puntuación <dbl> 85, 30, 20
```

From there, you can use the `mutate` function from tidyverse's `dplyr` (as above) to make the remaining calculations.

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a possible solution, that is not well and perfectly automatized, is done using the following code.

```
tpg$Puntuación[1] <- (as.numeric(as.character(tpg[1,2]))/120*5)


tpg$Puntuación[2] <- (as.numeric(as.character(tpg[2,2]))/45*5)


tpg$Puntuación[2] <- (as.numeric(as.character(tpg[3,2]))/30*5)
```

I wonder if there is a way to use a     `for` with an   `if else` to be more efficient doing this.

Thank you again